# How do I disable the chrome from auto filling in a certain field?

Tags: google-chrome

In my WordPress admin when I edit a user profile it auto fills in one of the passwords which is massively inconvenient since every time I hit save it errors our saying I have to input my password twice and forgets my changes. Is it possible to disable the auto-fill in this case?